# How to use discriminated union with enum as discriminant

Tags: typescript

I have a discriminated union where the discriminator is an enum and the value of the enum field determines whether or not another field is undefined.  As so:

```
enum Status {
  TOP, BOTTOM, MIDDLE
}
type StatusReport = 
| {
  status: Status.TOP | Status.BOTTOM
  message: undefined
} 
| {
  status: Status.MIDDLE
  message: string
}
```

All fine.  Now I introduce a function to build such a type from the appropriate parameters:

```
function statusReporter(theStatus: Status, statusMessage:string):StatusReport{
  return {
    status: theStatus,
    message: theStatus === Status.MIDDLE ? statusMessage : undefined
  }
}
```

This function logic looks sound to me.  It will assign the correct value to `message` depending on the value of the enum value being set in `status`.  But TS errors claiming Status is not assignable to type Status.MIDDLE.  That's true, of course, but I believe my conditional is ensuring that won't happen.

Why am I getting this error and what's the fix?

Here's [the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAygLgQzmAzlA3gWAFBSgFQHkAFAGigCFD8iBZc2gSQBFmAZAURwF8c4BPAA7BYiZCgBKwQQHsATnCgBeKDgA%20GHHhRjUALlFJUAOiLEoG%20EZTGqNQrS1QIwFCgQBzYAbAgAJsAAZgCWIMB%20PKrYGli4UDrWBlbixkysnE4ubp7e8XByoR48ODiBvgDGcMEyIHnWUrIKwHIAFHAAFsDJ%20obi5AnitK7uXno6BSAeAJR63ZLS8nCxeHLAyHK1y3h14gYdXboopE54WSO5%203PKSipzqSzsHFAA-DuoQ9leUD7%20QaHhTl42G4QA)

I've tried asserting the type of `theStatus` as a conditional type dependent on whether or not `theStatus` extends `Status.MIDDLE` (`status: theStatus as typeof theStatus extends Status.MIDDLE ? Status.MIDDLE : Status`), but it doesn't help.  I get the same error.

Comment: [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAygLgQzmAzlA3gWAFBSgFQHkAFAGigCFD8iBZc2gSQBFmAZAURwF8c4BPAA7BYiZCgBKwQQHsATnCgBeKDgA+GHHhRjUALlFJUAOiLEoG+EZTGqNQrS1QIwFCgQBzYAbAgAJsAAZgCWIMB+PKrYGli4UDrWBlbixkysnE4ubp7e8XByoR48ODiBvgDGcMEyIHnWUrIKwHIAFHAAFsDJ+obi5AnitK7uXno6BSAeAJR63ZLS8nCxeHLAyHK1HV26aEp7vSZp7BxQAPyacdo7BltzpE54WSO5A6hD2V5O3FAGy3h14hunTuD2cwxyPn8QVC4S+PCAA). You apparently have to determine the type before you create your object.

Comment: @ferikeem Ah.  That does work.  I guess once you are inside the object TS won't further narrow?  If you want to write this up an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to determine the type before you create your object.

```
function statusReporter(theStatus: Status, statusMessage:string):StatusReport{
  return theStatus === Status.MIDDLE ? {
    status: theStatus,
    message: statusMessage
  } : {
    status: theStatus,
    message: undefined
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=2&pln=13&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAygLgQzmAzlA3gWAFBSgFQHkAFAGigCFD8iBZc2gSQBFmAZAURwF8c4BPAA7BYiZCgBKwQQHsATnCgBeKDgA%20GHHhRjUALlFJUAOiLEoG%20EZTGqNQrS1QIwFCgQBzYAbAgAJsAAZgCWIMB%20PKrYGli4UDrWBlbixkysnE4ubp7e8XByoR48ODiBvgDGcMEyIHnWUrIKwHIAFHAAFsDJ%20obi5AnitK7uXno6BSAeAJR63ZLS8nCxeHLAyHK1HV26aEp7vSZp7BxQAPyacdo7BltzpE54WSO5A6hD2V5O3FAGy3h14hunTuD2cwxyPn8QVC4S%20PCAA)

Comment: this is the correct answer, though note that @captain-yossarian provides what i believe is the correct explanation for the behavior, namely, that conditional expressions evaluate to unions and so, if they are inside the object, the required narrowing won't happen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use function [overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```js
enum Status {
  TOP, BOTTOM, MIDDLE
}

type WithoutMessage = {
  status: Status.TOP | Status.BOTTOM
  message: undefined
}
type WithMessage = {
  status: Status.MIDDLE
  message: string
}

type StatusReport = WithMessage | WithoutMessage


function statusReporter(theStatus: Status.MIDDLE, statusMessage: string): WithMessage
function statusReporter(theStatus: Exclude<Status, Status.MIDDLE>, statusMessage: string): WithoutMessage
function statusReporter(theStatus: Status, statusMessage: string): StatusReport
function statusReporter(theStatus: Status, statusMessage: string) {
  return {
    status: theStatus,
    message: theStatus === Status.MIDDLE ? statusMessage : undefined
  }
}

function builder(myStatus: Status) {
  return statusReporter(myStatus, "hello");
};
const hof = builder(Status.MIDDLE) // StatusReport

const result = statusReporter(Status.MIDDLE, 'hello') // WithMessage
const result2 = statusReporter(Status.BOTTOM, 'hello') // WithoutMessage
const result3 = statusReporter(Status.TOP, 'hello') // WithoutMessage
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAygLgQzmAzlA3gWAFBSgFQHkAFAGigCFD8iBZc2gSQBFmAZAURwF8cc4AngAdgUAOoBLOAAsA9mDi1gKFAgDmogLwYceFImQoAXLAOoAdEWJQAPqaQWqNQrV1QIy1RpNgQAE2AAMwkQYD8efmFRSRklFXUtHVwofQdje0NzJlZONw947xS4ACcQtQjsSJEM1AAlYCFZYrgobRjpOK9RO3b5RU8EvkrsQN8AYzgJWRAitPrG5uBigAoZYHg0kw3M7PYOclTDToSTfVKQNQBKE3bjjRxRkAmpmcO6hqa4JdXpdbN0jgADzGABswAEADzbVDkaEoLIsPYAPgO-zuwFOJTK13EUjkCnRD3Gk2ms0M80+3zWcK2-1RaXRmPOV1pcw+zSJTxJr3+FMWK2p-1ZhnpRwGhTO2KSeGKwGQxRmWGSeiFUEFaVIbjw+S6JnVhlamm0cIROQ4UAA-GTUOioD5-EEQmE3LxsK7Oc9SQAjMASEEBFYQAQ0mooS7SqCy+U8tkLL6B4N0qAAIl+IJBsmTlwA3Dxc9gxtN9FA5IFWlAfX6A8sTbtOOGAPQN0N8uBDQsgYuylBgEEtbRvFCt761xGccgAcjTGYnjebt3FwBwHa7yl7cAATOXB8OVianHRJ9PZLOoE3cTI+oSC0WWt31wBmbe89nxmv-SwkI-AdMnucX-F+gKYAgA)

You are getting this error because `message` property evaluates to `string | undefined` while `StatusReport` expects either `undefined` or `message` but not both, I mean not union of them

**UPDATE**

```js
function statusReporter(theStatus: Status, statusMessage: string): StatusReport {
  if (theStatus === Status.MIDDLE) {
    return {
      status: theStatus,
      message: statusMessage
    }
  }
  return {
    status: theStatus,
    message: undefined
  }
}
```

Comment: Using overloads here basically only works because it disables (most) type-checking of the return value; you can replace the function body with `return {};` and there is no error. You might as well just use a type assertion instead.

Comment: right; that's my concern with an overload approach.  for example this extension to @captain-yossarian's code will not return the expected type:
`function builder(myStatus: Status){
  return statusReporter(myStatus, "hello");};
builder(Status.MIDDLE) // WithoutMessage -- BUT should be WithMessage`